# Указание конкретного параметра среди необязательных параметров TypeScript

Tags: функции, typescript, optional

У меня есть такая функция

```
searchCars(city: string, startDate: string, endDate: string, minAmount?: number, maxAmount?: number, ascending?: boolean,
         itemsOnPage?: number, currentPage?: number) {
some code 
}
```

Мне надо ее вызвать с параметрами city, startDate, endDate, itemsOnPage и currentPage. Я могу это сделать способом отличным от этого?

```
searchCars(city, startDate, endDate, undefined, undefined,undefined, itemsOnPage, currentPage)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот не могу ответить конкретно на этот вопрос, хотя думаю, что нет, нельзя, но лучше такое объявление функции избегать и делать что-то типа конфиг-объекта.

```js
interface Options {
  mandatory1: string;
  mandatory2: number;
  optional1?: string;
  optional2?: boolean
}

function fn(opts: Options) {
  // code here
  opts.mandatory1
  // ну и так далее
}
```

Мне так видится, хотя на тс недавно совсем писать начал.

Comment: Тоже думал о чем то подобном, в гугле ничего не нашел. Подожду еще и буду так делать